# Wolfram answer is different for the integral $\sqrt{\frac{x}{2-x}}dx$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

$$I=\sqrt{\frac{x}{2-x}}dx=\int \frac{xdx}{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}=\frac{-1}{2} \times \int\frac{(2-2x-2)dx}{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}$$ so

$$I=\frac{-1}{2}\int\frac{(2-2x)dx}{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}+\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}$$ so

$$I=-\sqrt{2x-x^2}+\sin^{-1}(x-1)+C$$

But wolfram gave a very complicated answer which is shown in the image below:
[image]

Comment: The logarithmic term is actually the arcsin function in disguise because of complex number magic. Wolfram Alpha is programmed to think logarithms are 'simpler' than trig functions even if the resulting expresion is longer.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of question is more suitable in [Mathematica stackexchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

To answer this question, both are right. To have a better result, it is better to specify the interval, i.e.,

```
Integrate[ Sqrt[x/(2 - x)], {x, 0, y}]
```

which gives the answer 
$$2 \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\sqrt{(2-x) x},$$
instead of

```
 Integrate[ Sqrt[x/(2 - x)], x]
```

To show that they are indeed identical (up to a additive constant). You can directly plot everything together.

```
Plot[{Re[2 I Log[Sqrt[-2 + x] + Sqrt[x]]], 2     
   ArcSin[Sqrt[x]/Sqrt[2]], 
   ArcSin[x - 1]} , {x, 0, 2}
```

[image: ]]

Answer (score 1):

As $x(2-x)>0, x(x-2)<0,2>x>0$

WLOG let $x=1+\cos2y$ and $0\le2y\le\pi$

$\implies\sqrt{\dfrac x{2-x}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1+\cos2y}{1-\cos2y}}=+\cot y$

$\displaystyle\int\sqrt{\dfrac x{2-x}}dx=\int\cot y(-2\sin2y)dy=-2\int(1+\cos2y)dy=-2y-\sin2y+K$
$=-\arccos(x-1)-\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}+K$

$=\arcsin(x-1)-\sqrt{2x-x^2}+K-\dfrac\pi2$

Comment: @DavidH, Sorry for the typo